# AppCatalog resource permissions is missing for v2.0 apps

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to install app to microsoft teams using Microsoft graph api. But it requires "AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All" permission which is missing in v2 app registraion portal.(https://apps.dev.microsoft.com).

Do I need to switch from v2 to v1 app?

Comment: Note that with the introduction of the new preview experience for App registrations (see Lesia's answer below), there is no longer really a distinction between a "v1 app" and a "v2 app" in terms of the registration itself. The only distinction will be in what endpoint (v1 or v2) the registered app is calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to—you can request this permission using the [preview experience for App registrations](http://aka.ms/AppRegistrationsPreview). First, find your app in the preview experience. Navigate to `API permissions` and click the `Add a permission` button. Select `Microsoft Graph`, then select `Delegated permissions`. Locate the `AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All` permission and select it. Lastly, click `Add permissions`.